# online safety vs. online security

Tags: vocabulary

Is there any difference between "online safety" and "online security" (or for that matter, between "internet safety" and "internet security")? Is the difference parallel to that between "food safety" and "food security"?

Comment: The word-pair ***food security*** isn't a well-established collocation, but to the extent that it *does* occur, it would normally refer to *ensuring that **food supply chains** operate properly* (i.e. - that there ***is*** food, and it ***can*** be delivered to the people who need to eat it). And ***food safety*** either refers to whether or not *eating* the food might make people ill (is it ***safe to eat**?*).

Answer (score 1):

While cyber***security protects devices and networks*** from harm by third parties, Online ***Safety protects the people using them*** from harm by the devices and networks (and therefor third parties) through awareness, education, information and technology. Ref [**What is online safety**/](https://swgfl.org.uk/online-safety/what-is-online-safety/)

---

Is the difference parallel to that between "food safety" and "food security"?

The answer to this depends on your opinion on what does food security means. In its shortest form it means Have you got/are you able to get-food. In this case there is a difference between food security and the protection of your PC from viruses and ransom ware.

Comment: Food safety is protecting the consumer, where as food security is protecting the supply chain, so it is pretty similar to internet security.

Comment: @JavaLatte OL Security is used by the end user Food Security is used by the supplier. Therefore cannot be the same. The target market is different and the technique used is very different.

Comment: our opinions differ on that one.